# Storing Loop Variables in Different CSV Files

Tags: python, csv

For a current project, I am looping a script and storing respective variables on a "loop by loop" basis.

As a next step, I am planning to store these variable "sets" in separate CSV files. The current script however adds up all variables and assigns them to the same file with cumulated values.

Is there any smart tweak to have the output saved on a loop by loop basis? The corresponding part of the code looks like this:

```
# Looping output
    output = []
    elements = [0, 44]
    for x in elements:
        output.append(x)

        # Print the contents of dictionary
        for key in list(d.keys()):
            print(key, ":", d[key])

            # Count the total number of words
            total = sum(d.values())
            percent = d[key] / total

            print(d[key], total, percent)

            # Saving the content in a CSV file
            with open('Glassdoor_A.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
                writer = csv.writer(file)
                writer.writerow(["Word", "Occurrences", "Percentage"])
                writer.writerows([key, d[key], d[key] / total] for key in list(d.keys()))
```

Comment: Have a file name as a variable and update it before you enter the inner loop.

Comment: Thanks for the good idea - would you set this up via .append()?

Comment: You need to have unique **file name** for each iteration of your outer loop. Name = String of text. You actual code will depend on the naming pattern you decide to implement.

Comment: Ok that's understood. The loops include a broader number of variables per iteration, so just thinking what name/string can be taken for it.

Comment: The easiest will be `'somename' + str(i)` where `i` is a self-incrementing counter.

Comment: Let me see if I can figure out a solution on that basis. Many thanks already.

Comment: I have added `numbers = [0, 44], for i in numbers: name = 'Glassdoor_A' + str(i), file = open(name.csv, 'w', newline='')` but am receiving the following error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'csv'`. There are some threads on this error but none that could clarify things yet. Do you know what was to be changed to make it work?

Comment: What is `name.csv`???  Did you mean `name+'.csv'`?